# Edit Post Counter Stays Hard Coded on Magento.SE

Tags: discussion, edits, profile-page, badge-progress

Most of the time I can see on Magento.SE that some users always keep editing posts whether it's going to be helpful or not. (That's not my concern).

I did that same thing today (For checking editing counter) I've edited exactly 8 posts on that site, but still the counter didn't increase.

Check below Screen:

> [image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/; also, edits on own posts or posts you already edited don't count.

Comment: @Glorfindel What ?

Comment: It's not updated real-time.

Comment: Oh Cool So whtat's schedule ? Obviously there would be some time.

Comment: While @Glorfindel is correct, that's not the case here. The caching is likely around 10-20 minutes, but in the specific case you bring here, the answer by Catija is correct, and all edits you made were not relevant towards this counter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tag edits don't count. It says that in the badge description. Only two of your five suggested edits on Magento were approved and all they changed were the tags. This is behaving as designed.

[image: Badge description shows tag edits don't count]